# Can't (re-)authorize any Accessibility apps on Monterey (12.6.3)

Tags: security, automation, privacy, accessibility

After a forced reboot (and another reboot for good measure), the applications I allow to "Accessibility" control under System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy no longer includes Rectangle.app nor allows me to add it manually.

Nothing appears there anymore and nothing can be added. [image]

Comment: Helpful but frustrating. What reboots could not fix, a shutdown and start: did.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately I've solve my issue. The solution is frustrating.

What reboots could not fix, a shutdown and start did. Know that system behavior after a reboot may differ from system behavior after a shutdown and start up, manually sequenced.

In evidence, here are some of the Accessibility authorized apps after restart, including the Rectangle app of concern.
[image]